# Nestjs - Mongoose - virtual field - Not able to Query in graphql playground

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, mongodb-query, nestjs

I am trying to create a virtual field in nestjs-mongoose.
The code is not showing any error but I was not able to query that virtual field in graphql playground.

I tired adding a virtual field by using schema.virtual("virtualFieldName").
Then I enabled the {virtuals: true} for the respective schema. But still not able to query this field.

Should I need to add anything in DTO file?

**Entity.ts / Schema file**

````
@Schema({
  collection: 'v3_customer_account_selectors',
  timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at', updatedAt: 'updated_at' },
  toJSON: { virtuals: true },
})
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.TRANSIENT })
export class AccountSelectorEntity extends BaseEntity {

  @AliasableProp({ alias: '_type', type: AccountSelectorType })
  type: AccountSelectorType;

  @Prop()
  name?: string;

  @AliasableProp({ alias: 'last_checked', type: Date })
  lastChecked?: Date;

  @AliasableProp({
    type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
    alias: 'customer_id',
  })
  customerId?: Types.ObjectId;
}

export const AccountSelectorEntitySchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(
  AccountSelectorEntity
);

AccountSelectorEntitySchema.set('toJSON', { getters: true, virtual: true });
AccountSelectorEntitySchema.set('toObject', { getters: true, virtual: true });

AccountSelectorEntitySchema.virtual('selector_type').get(function () {
  return 'TestReturn';
});```
````

Answer (score 1):

You must to create a type or another class instead using an entity. Entity virtuals not in entity document class.